# Prove $\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1-x}\ dx=\zeta(3)-\frac32\ln2\zeta(2)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-zeta

How to prove without using Euler sums that

> $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1-x}\ dx=\zeta(3)-\frac32\ln2\zeta(2)$$

where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.

We can relate this integral to some Euler sum as follows:

\begin{align}
I&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\int_0^1\frac{x^n\ln x}{1-x}\ dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}(H_n^{(2)}-\zeta(2))\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(2)}}{n}-\ln2\zeta(2)
\end{align}

Also the integral $I$ can be related to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^2}$. So I am looking for a different way to evaluate $I$ besides using these two sums.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1-x}\,dx\end{align}
Always the same story...

For $x\in [0;1]$ define the function $R$ by,\begin{align}R(x)&=\int_0^x \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(tx)}{1-tx}\,dt\\
J&=\Big[R(x)\ln(1+x)\Big]_0^1-\int_0^1 \frac{R(x)}{(1+x)} dx\\
&=-\zeta(2)\ln 2-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(tx)}{(1-tx)(1+x)}\,dt\,dx\\
&=-\zeta(2)\ln 2-\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln t}{(1-tx)(1+x)}\,dx\right)\,dt-\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{(1-tx)(1+x)}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
&=-\zeta(2)\ln 2+\int_0^1\left[\frac{\ln(1-tx)}{t(1+t)}+\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+t}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}\ln t\,dt+\int_0^1\left[\frac{\ln(1-tx)}{1+x}\right]_{t=0}^{t=1}\ln x\,dx\\
&=-\zeta(2)\ln 2+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-t)\ln t}{t(1+t)}\,dt+\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}\,dt+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln x}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=-\zeta(2)\ln 2+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-t)\ln t}{t}\,dt+\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}\,dt\\
&=-\zeta(2)\ln 2+\frac{1}{2}\left(\Big[\ln^2 x\ln(1-x)\Big]+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t }{1-t}\,dt\right)+\ln 2\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{2t\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt\right)
\end{align}
In the last integral perform the change of variable $y=t^2$,
\begin{align}J&=-\zeta(2)\ln 2+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt+\ln 2\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt\right)\\
&=-\frac{3}{2}\zeta(2)\ln 2+\frac{1}{2}\times 2\zeta(3)\\
&=\boxed{-\frac{3}{2}\zeta(2)\ln 2+\zeta(3)}
\end{align}
NB: i assume,\begin{align}R(1)&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=-\zeta(2)\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt&=2\zeta(3)\end{align}

Comment: nice approach..

Answer (score 8):

Start off with the substitution $x\to \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ to get:
$$\require{cancel} I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1-x}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)}{x}dx-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}dx$$

$$X=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln 2 -\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)-\ln(1+x)\ln 2+\ln^2(1+x)}{x}dx$$
$$Y=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln 2 -\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)-\ln(1+x)\ln 2+\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x}dx$$

---

$$I_1=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx=\color{blue}{-\ln 2 \zeta(2)}$$
[$$I_2=-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=\color{red}{\frac{5}{8}\zeta(3)}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3085715/515527)
$$I_3=-\ln 2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=\color{blue}{-\frac{\ln 2}{2}\zeta(2)}$$
[$$I_4=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x}dx=\color{red}{\frac{\zeta(3)}{4}}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2143161/515527)
[$$I_5=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}dx=\cancel{\frac{\ln^3 2}{2}}-\cancel{\ln 2\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/117246/515527)
[$$I_6=-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx =\cancel{-\frac{\ln^3 2}{3}}+\cancel{\ln 2\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}}-\color{red}{\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3200438/515527)
$$I_7=-\ln 2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx=\cancel{-\frac{\ln^3 2}{2}}$$
$$I_8=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x}dx=\cancel{\frac{\ln^3 2}{3}}$$

---

$$I=X-Y=(I_1+I_2+I_3+I_4)-(I_5+I_6+I_7+I_8)=\boxed{\zeta(3)-\frac32 \ln 2 \zeta(2)}$$

Comment: (+1) For the brilliance of the solution.

Comment: nice idea Zacky.

Comment: @Zacky would you mind writing the website you sent me before where i can find $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+x)\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx$? because I posted solution there and I need it as a ref.

Comment: @AliShather https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u380742h1883703p12826640

Comment: @Zacky thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You might need the first generalization from the preprint [A simple strategy of calculating two alternating harmonic series generalizations by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333339284_A_simple_strategy_of_calculating_two_alternating_harmonic_series_generalizations). All the calculations are accomplished by avoiding the evaluation of Euler sums.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^{(m)}}{n}=\frac{(-1)^m}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{\displaystyle \log^{m-1}(x)\log\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x
$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\biggr(m\zeta (m+1)-2\log (2) \left(1-2^{1-m}\right) \zeta (m)$$
$$-\sum_{k=1}^{m-2} \left(1-2^{-k}\right)\left(1-2^{1+k-m}\right)\zeta (k+1)\zeta (m-k)\biggr).$$

Comment: I am familiar with these generalizations .. very useful but how about to do it on our own?

Comment: I started from the assumption you weren't aware of it since you didn't mention it, and then you didn't ask for ways which didn't appear in the mathematical literature yet.

Comment: I am very familiar with Cornel's papers but I am really into independent solutions ( if possible) that does not reply much on other results/ generalizations.

Comment: Of course you are into independent solutions. The manipulations with double integrals seems to make it very easy.

Comment: that's the way to go :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the integral $$K=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1+x}\ dx$$

By applying IBP we have

$$K=\ln(2)\zeta(2)+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx\tag{1}$$

.

---

On the other hand

\begin{align}
K&=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1+x}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}\left(\int_0^1-\frac{x\ln u}{1-xu}\ du\right)\ dx\\
&=\int_0^1\ln u\left(\int_0^1\frac{-x}{(1+x)(1-ux)}\ dx\right)\ du\\
&=\int_0^1\ln u\left(\frac{\ln2}{1+u}+\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u}-\frac{\ln(1-u)}{1+u}\right)\ du\\
&=\ln2\int_0^1\frac{\ln u}{1+u}\ du+\int_0^1\frac{\ln u\ln(1-u)}{u}\ du-\color{blue}{\int_0^1\frac{\ln u\ln(1-u)}{1+u}\ du}\\
&\overset{\color{blue}{IBP}}{=}\ln2\left(-\frac12\zeta(2)\right)+\zeta(3)\color{blue}{-\int_0^1\frac{\ln u\ln(1+u)}{1-u}du+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-u)\ln(1+u)}{u}du}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

Combining (1) and (2) we get

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1-x}\ dx=\zeta(3)-\frac32\ln2\zeta(2)$$

Comment: (+1) Definitely one of the best solutions.

Comment: Thank you @user97357329 .

Comment: I think one can make things a little more simpler because $(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2=4ab$

Comment: @FDP this method is done by Zacky here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3085715 but thats not enough to solve the problem.

Comment: @Ali Shather: if you want to compute $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx$, for me, it's enough.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1-x}\,\dd x =
\zeta\pars{3} - {3 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2}\zeta\pars{2}}:\
\approx 0.5082\ {\Large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x} =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{2\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} + \ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} -
\bracks{\ln\pars{x} - \ln\pars{1 + x}}^{\, 2} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x +
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} - \ln^{2}\pars{2} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] & \!\!\!\!
-{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}
\bracks{\ln^{2}\pars{x \over x + 1} - \ln^{2}\pars{2}}
\,{\dd x \over 1 - x}
\end{align}
In the $\underline{second}$ integral I'll make the change
$\ds{1 + x \mapsto 2x}$ while $\ds{x/\pars{x + 1} \mapsto x}$ in the $\underline{third}$ one. Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x +
{1 \over 2}\int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{2x} - \ln^{2}\pars{2} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] & \!\!\!\!
-{1 \over 2}\bracks{%
-\int_{0}^{1/2}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} - \ln^{2}\pars{2} \over 1 - x}
\,\dd x +
2\int_{0}^{1/2}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} - \ln^{2}\pars{2} \over 1 - 2x}
\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x +
{1 \over 2}\int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{2x} - \ln^{2}\pars{2} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] & \!\!\!\!
+ \bracks{%
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1/2}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x 
- {1 \over 2}\ln^{3}\pars{2}
- {1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x/2} -
\ln^{2}\pars{2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,
-\int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x 
+ \bracks{%
{1 \over 2}\ln^{3}\pars{2} -\int_{1/2}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\ln\pars{2x}\,\dd x}
\\[2mm] & \phantom{\stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,\,\,}
+ \bracks{{1 \over 2}\ln^{3}\pars{2}
-\int_{0}^{1/2}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x}
\\[2mm]& \phantom{\stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,\,\,}
-{1 \over 2}\ln^{3}\pars{2}
+ \int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\ln\pars{x \over 2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{x}\,\dd x +
{1 \over 2}\ln^{3}\pars{2}
-\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1}\ln\pars{2} +
\int_{1/2}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] & \phantom{\stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,\,\,}
-\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{1 \over 2} +
\int_{0}^{1/2}\mrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
+\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1}\ln\pars{1 \over 2}
\\[2mm] & \phantom{\stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,\,\,}
-\int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,
\zeta\pars{3} + {1 \over 2}\ln^{3}\pars{2}
-2\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1}\ln\pars{2} +
\zeta\pars{3} - \mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 \over 2}
\\[2mm] & \phantom{\stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,\,\,}
+ \mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{2} +
\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 \over 2} - \zeta\pars{3}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\ln^{3}\pars{2}
-2\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1}\ln\pars{2} +
\zeta\pars{3} + \mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{2}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] & \phantom{\stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,\,\,} =
\bbx{\large\zeta\pars{3} - {3 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2}\zeta\pars{2}}
\approx 0.5082\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

In (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}) I used $\ds{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1} =
\zeta\pars{2} = \pi^{2}/6}$ and the
[known values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values) of
$\ds{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1/2}}$ and $\ds{\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1/2}}$.

Comment: Very nice solution.. +1